# SQL - Return first non NULL Value after RANK() or ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, row-number

Question on the following :

I have a table (Client) that holds multiple records with the same username (unfortunately it's a limitation of the front end of the software).  When I join to that table on username, it obviously returns multiple rows.  Typically I use ROW_NUMBER(), partition by the username and order on a field I want and then join to limit the result set to one and return the desired columns and this has worked well in the past.  However, I'm attempting to use this in a way I haven't before... I'm partitioning by username, and ordering by the date the record was last updated in an effort to return a third field, in this case address.  Observe the following table results :

```
Username|UpdatedDate|Address
JSmith  |10-10-14   |NULL
JSmith  |05-24-14   |1 Main Street
```

The object is to return the most up to date record but if the latest record doesn't contain the Address, to grab the address from the previous record.

Is this possible?

EDIT :

@Gordon...perhaps I'm misunderstanding something but in the first approach, the last updated date isn't taken into account when ordering. So if the table looks like :

```
JSmith|10-10-14|1 Main
JSmith|04-20-14|1 Main 
JSmith|01-10-13|5 Main
```

It will return 1 for all rows.  The ultimate goal is that if there only one record, to grab that one record.  If there is multiple records, to grab the most up to date record, but then if the address is NULL, grab the the next most up to date record with an address.

Comment: Just use `Where Address Is Not Null`.  If the most up-to-date record is `NULL`, it would skip to the first populated record.  If it isn't `NULL`, it wouldn't matter/

Comment: But if there is only one record and use WHERE ADDRESS IS NOT NULL, it wouldn't return the single record, no?

Comment: @EmptySet . . . Your edit doesn't make sense.  According to your rules, the first row is the correct row to return.

Comment: @GordonLinoff... you're right, i would want the first row but the code would return all three rows as they would all have a 1 for their ROW_NUMBER.  That's been my experience when I originally wrote it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the right `row_number()` logic:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by username
                                order by (case when address is not null then 1 else 2 end), UpdatedDate desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from clients c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

Of course, if you don't mind filtering out `username`s that have no address, you could use:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by username
                                order by UpdatedDate desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from clients c
      where address is not null
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

But you might end up losing some records.

Comment: Your second approach is where I started but you're correct, I end up losing records where we only have one record but there is no address for that record.  I still need to return that.

Comment: @EmptySet . . . Hence the first approach.

Comment: I updated my original post to hopefully explain better what I meant.

Comment: yeah the first approach would not return the latest record

Answer (score 1):

Use an apply operator to locate the most recent address, in addition to the row_number(), so that you get the full row of the most recent data plus the most recent address even if that happens to be null in the most recent row.

```
SELECT
    c.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        c.*
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY username
                           ORDER BY UpdatedDate DESC) AS seqnum
      , COALESCE(c.address, oa.lastaddress) AS lastaddress
    FROM clients c
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP (1)
            address AS lastaddress
        FROM clients c2
        WHERE c.username = c2.username
        AND c2.adress IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY
            UpdatedDate DESC
    ) oa
) c
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```