# Return non-null values for every field in ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider this data:

```
CREATE TABLE #FakeTable (

PersonID varchar(255)
,PatientNM varchar(255)
,BirthDTS varchar(255)
,PhoneNBR varchar(255)
,EmailAddress varchar(255)
,StreetAddress varchar(255)
,KeyFieldCNT int

)

INSERT INTO #FakeTable (PersonID, PatientNM, BirthDTS, PhoneNBR, EmailAddress, StreetAddress, KeyFieldCNT)
VALUES('123456', 'Jerry Garcia', NULL, NULL, 'fake@noemail.com', NULL, 11),
        ('123456', 'Jerry Garcia', '19421401', '999-999-9999', NULL, NULL, 11),
        ('123456', 'Jerry Garcia', '19421401', '999-999-9999', 'fake@noemail.com', '123 Fake Street', 9),
        ('7891011', 'Bob Weir', '19471610', NULL, NULL, '456 Nope Street', 11),
        ('7891011', 'Bob Weir', NULL, NULL, 'nope@fake.com', '456 Nope Street', 10),
        ('7891011', 'Bob Weir', '19471610', NULL, 'nope@fake.com', '456 Nope Street', 6)
```

And we then have:

```
PersonID  PatientNM     BirthDTS       PhoneNBR      EmailAddress        StreetAddress    KeyFieldCNT
123456    Jerry Garcia   NULL          NULL          fake@noemail.com    NULL               11
123456    Jerry Garcia   19421401      999-999-9999  NULL                NULL               11
123456    Jerry Garcia   19421401      999-999-9999  fake@noemail.com    123 Fake Street    9
7891011   Bob Weir       19471610      NULL          NULL                456 Nope Street    11
7891011   Bob Weir       NULL          NULL          nope@fake.com       456 Nope Street    10
7891011   Bob Weir       19471610      NULL          nope@fake.com       456 Nope Street    6
```

I want to use ROW_NUMBER() and partition by the PersonID and order by the KeyFieldCNT, in order to establish a ranking.  I would like the top ranking row to return only non-null values for each column, if that column happens to be populated in another lower ranking row.

Using just a normal ROW_NUMBER() and partition/order by, here are the results:

```
WITH CTE AS (

SELECT *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY KeyFieldCNT DESC) AS RowNBR
FROM #FakeTable

)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNBR = '1'
```

Results In:

```
PersonID  PatientNM     BirthDTS  PhoneNBR       EmailAddress      StreetAddress      KeyFieldCNT   RowNBR
123456    Jerry Garcia  NULL      NULL           fake@noemail.com    NULL               11          1
7891011   Bob Weir      19471610  NULL           NULL                456 Nope Street    11          1
```

My Desired results are these:

```
PersonID  PatientNM     BirthDTS  PhoneNBR       EmailAddress      StreetAddress      KeyFieldCNT   RowNBR
123456    Jerry Garcia  19421401  999-999-9999   fake@noemail.com  123 Fake Street    11            1
7891011   Bob Weir      19471610  NULL           nope@fake.com     456 Nope Street    11            1
```

Does anyone know how to do this?  I have tried using this as an example, but it is not giving me what I need when I extrapolate to more than just one field of interest ([SQL - Return first non NULL Value after RANK() or ROW_NUMBER()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463150/sql-return-first-non-null-value-after-rank-or-row-number)).

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by no repro? And what works as expected on db fiddle?

Comment: Never mind, I missed the KeyFieldCnt was different at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
CREATE TABLE #FakeTable (

PersonID varchar(255)
,PatientNM varchar(255)
,BirthDTS varchar(255)
,PhoneNBR varchar(255)
,EmailAddress varchar(255)
,StreetAddress varchar(255)
,KeyFieldCNT int

)

INSERT INTO #FakeTable (PersonID, PatientNM, BirthDTS, PhoneNBR, EmailAddress, StreetAddress, KeyFieldCNT)
VALUES('123456', 'Jerry Garcia', NULL, NULL, 'fake@noemail.com', NULL, 11),
        ('123456', 'Jerry Garcia', '19421401', '999-999-9999', NULL, NULL, 11),
        ('123456', 'Jerry Garcia', '19421401', '999-999-9999', 'fake@noemail.com', '123 Fake Street', 9),
        ('7891011', 'Bob Weir', '19471610', NULL, NULL, '456 Nope Street', 11),
        ('7891011', 'Bob Weir', NULL, NULL, 'nope@fake.com', '456 Nope Street', 10),
        ('7891011', 'Bob Weir', '19471610', NULL, 'nope@fake.com', '456 Nope Street', 6)

    SELECT ft.PersonID,
           ft.PatientNM,
           MAX(ft.BirthDTS) AS BirthDTS,
           MAX(ft.PhoneNBR) AS PhoneNBR,
           MAX(ft.EmailAddress) AS EmailAddress,
           MAX(ft.StreetAddress) AS StreetAddress,
           MAX(ft.KeyFieldCNT) AS  KeyFieldCNT
    FROM #FakeTable AS ft
    GROUP BY PersonID, ft.PatientNM
```

Comment: This doesn't return the highest KeyFieldCNT that I want.  I forgot to add DESC in the ORDER BY, my mistake.

Comment: If a patient data changes over time it might also show the values from older records.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem. When filtering with `row_number()`, the values for all of the columns will come from the **same row**. This is actually a **feature**; it's a *good thing*, and the main reason I've been slowly replacing a lot of old `GROUP BY` code to use `row_number()` instead.

But for person ID 123456 you want to see non-NULL data for both `PhoneNBR` and `EmailAddress`, and also show the highest value (`11`) for `KeyFieldCNT`.

**There is no such row in the table.**

Both rows for person 123456 with KeyFieldCount = 11 are missing one field or the other.

I suspect `KeyFieldCnt` is maintained by the application to show how many of certain fields are populated, and you want to show the row for each user with the most data. Unfortunately, that row is missing one of the fields you care about, even if it has more of the others.

There are ways around this, but if you need to be able to merge data with multiple possible missing fields you will have to join back to the table again for each possible field... potentially quite slow and lengthy. Instead, this seems like a data problem. The table is not storing all the data in all the places you expect, and the better solution is to find and restore/repair the missing data in the table.

Assuming `PatientID`, `PatientNM`, and `KeyFieldCNT` cannot be NULL, you could try this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY KeyFieldCNT) AS RowNBR
    FROM FakeTable
)

SELECT CTE.PersonID, CTE.PatientNM, 
      coalesce(CTE.BirthDTS, max(ft.BirthDTS)) BirthDTS, 
      coalesce(CTE.PhoneNBR, max(ft.PhoneNBR)) PhoneNBR,
      coalesce(CTE.EmailAddress, max(ft.EmailAddress)) EmailAddress,
      coalesce(CTE.StreetAddress, max(ft.StreetAddress)) StreetAddress,
      CTE.KeyFieldCNT
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN FakeTable ft ON ft.PersonID = CTE.PersonID
WHERE RowNBR = 1
GROUP BY CTE.PersonID, CTE.PatientNM, CTE.BirthDTS, CTE.PhoneNBR,
         CTE.EmailAddress, CTE.StreetAddress, CTE.KeyFieldCNT
```

See it here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/Nqz61kul

Just be aware: this is mixing values from different rows, which is almost always a **bad idea**, and there is no meaningful selection for which row has priority to fill the missing data.

A **more correct** approach involves an additional scan of the table for each field you care about, so you can specify the priority and other criteria for filling in the missing values. But that will be *much longer* and *crazy slow*.

Comment: That's the gist of the question.  I need a solution based on the data that is present. The linked question seems to have a solution but not easily extrapolated to more than one column.

Comment: Unfortunatley, restoring/repairing the missing data into the table isn't an option.  This is what I have to work with.

Comment: Then you're back to re-reading the table for every possible field. That's gonna be hella slow.

Comment: So that is the only possible solution?

Comment: You can use aggregation, but then you're mixing values from different rows and there's no guarantee you're getting the most recent/relevant.

Comment: What do you mean use aggregation?

Comment: aggregation == group by. It's in the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried selecting each column individually with

```
SELECT TOP 1 <col> FROM ... WHERE <col> IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ... DESC
```

and it seems to do the trick, as follows:

```
;WITH X (PersonID) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT PersonID FROM #FakeTable
)
SELECT X.PersonID
     , (SELECT TOP 1 F.PatientNM     FROM #FakeTable F WHERE F.PersonID = X.PersonID
               AND   F.PatientNM     IS NOT NULL    ORDER BY F.KeyFieldCNT DESC)
                AS     PatientNM
     , (SELECT TOP 1 F.BirthDTS      FROM #FakeTable F WHERE F.PersonID = X.PersonID
               AND   F.BirthDTS      IS NOT NULL    ORDER BY F.KeyFieldCNT DESC)
                AS     BirthDTS
     , (SELECT TOP 1 F.PhoneNBR      FROM #FakeTable F WHERE F.PersonID = X.PersonID
               AND   F.PhoneNBR      IS NOT NULL    ORDER BY F.KeyFieldCNT DESC)
                AS     PhoneNBR
     , (SELECT TOP 1 F.EmailAddress  FROM #FakeTable F WHERE F.PersonID = X.PersonID
               AND   F.EmailAddress  IS NOT NULL    ORDER BY F.KeyFieldCNT DESC)
                AS     EmailAddress
     , (SELECT TOP 1 F.StreetAddress FROM #FakeTable F WHERE F.PersonID = X.PersonID
               AND   F.StreetAddress IS NOT NULL    ORDER BY F.KeyFieldCNT DESC)
                AS     StreetAddress
     , (SELECT TOP 1 F.KeyFieldCNT   FROM #FakeTable F WHERE F.PersonID = X.PersonID
               AND   F.KeyFieldCNT   IS NOT NULL    ORDER BY F.KeyFieldCNT DESC)
                AS     KeyFieldCNT
FROM X
```

Results:

| PersonID | PatientNM | BirthDTS | PhoneNBR | EmailAddress | StreetAddress | KeyFieldCNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Jerry Garcia | 19421401 | 999-999-9999 | fake@noemail.com | 123 Fake Street | 11 |
| 7891011 | Bob Weir | 19471610 | null | nope@fake.com | 456 Nope Street | 11 |

DB Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/ErNqLqXw

For completeness I used the same pattern also for the `KeyFieldCNT` column, which can be probably be simplified.

Furthermore I don't have `RowNBR`, it can't be determined and has no meaning as there isn't a single row that provides all data for a result row.

Answer (score -1):

When you want/need the record with all (or the most) non-NULL values on top, you can do this:

```sql
select *,
  IIF(PersonId is null,0,1) +
  IIF(PatientNM is null,0,1) +
  IIF(BirthDTS is null,0,1) +
  IIF(PhoneNBR is null,0,1) +
  IIF(EmailAddress is null,0,1) +
  IIF(StreetAddress is null,0,1) +
  IIF(KeyFieldCNT is null,0,1) ColumnsWithData
from #FakeTable
ORDER BY 
  IIF(PersonId is null,0,1) +
  IIF(PatientNM is null,0,1) +
  IIF(BirthDTS is null,0,1) +
  IIF(PhoneNBR is null,0,1) +
  IIF(EmailAddress is null,0,1) +
  IIF(StreetAddress is null,0,1) +
  IIF(KeyFieldCNT is null,0,1)     DESC
  ;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/8zW5QEcG)